# Connection refused in Android M while trying httprequest from Android Service

Tags: android, android-studio

```
IOException
01-11 18:28:25.304 W/System.err: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.42 refused
01-11 18:28:25.306 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:193)
01-11 18:28:25.306 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
01-11 18:28:25.306 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
01-11 18:28:25.306 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:370)
01-11 18:28:25.306 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
01-11 18:28:25.306 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
01-11 18:28:25.307 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
01-11 18:28:25.307 W/System.err:     at com.aceuat.sms.ACESMSGService.connectServerTeachr(ACESMSGService.java:213)
01-11 18:28:25.307 W/System.err:     at com.aceuat.sms.ACESMSGService$1$1.run(ACESMSGService.java:103)
01-11 18:28:25.307 W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
01-11 18:28:25.307 W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-11 18:28:25.307 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:190)
01-11 18:28:25.307 W/System.err:    ... 9 more
01-11 18:28:25.307 W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-11 18:28:25.313 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:619)
01-11 18:28:25.313 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:689)
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:849)
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:124)
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err:     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:149)
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err:    ... 9 more
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:604)
01-11 18:28:25.314 W/System.err:    ... 14 more
01-11 18:28:40.280 I/ACES: Service is still running
```

Its Working fine in android lower versions.

Comment: You need to request permissions to users for Android M and above. See this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: @JaniceKartika, for the Internet permission you only need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` whether you're using version M or pre-M Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

As the Problem shows: You need to add internet access permission in the app.

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application ...
 </manifest>
```

And at last when app asks for internet access in popup allow the app to use internet!

Comment: I don't think Marshmallow or higher version Android devices ask you to allow Internet permission at runtime.